# How to access database tables present on remote server in Oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have installed Oracle XE and Oracle apex on my machine and all works fine. I can access tables and create reports based on those tables. However I would like to know the possibility of connecting to another Oracle database which is running on a different machine through Oracle apex on my machine and build applications based on the remote database tables. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible? Yes, here's how:

- workspace you work with is *mapped* to some schema in your database
- connect as that user and create a **database link** to remote database
- access remote tables

  - via database link, or
  - create synonyms in your user, or
  - create views in your user, or
  - create materialized views in your user

  depending on what you plan to do with remote tables

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can execute SQL not only in the "local" Oracle database (where APEX runs in), but also on a remote Oracle instance. You can execute SQL queries or PL/SQL defined at the component-level on a remote database using REST Enabled SQL references.
Requirements for using REST Enabled SQL Service references:

- A remote database that includes Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS) 19.x or later on the front-end.
- An administrator must enable RESTful Services either at the workspace or instance-level

See this [blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/application-express-early-adopter:-rest-enabled-sql) for example and steps